# Неточности в поясняющем комментарии при защите вопроса

Tags: дефект, поддержка, статус-запланировано, локализация, страница-учётной-записи

[Что такое](https://www.google.ru/#newwindow=1&q=%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D1%83%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9+site:meta.ru.stackoverflow.com) [ассоциация учётных записей](https://www.google.ru/#newwindow=1&q=%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D1%83%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9+site:ru.stackoverflow.com)? Увидел в сообщении о защите вопроса [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/506597/199934):

> [бонус за ассоциацию учётных записей не учитывается](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user).

[Видимо](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/326972), имеются в виду 100 баллов, начисляемые пользователю в каждый из проектов Stack Exchange, если на одном из них он достигнет высокой репутации. Но тогда лучше, если ссылка будет вести [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), где поясняется, что за бонус, а не на [данную страницу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user), на которой тоже не до конца понятно, о каком «сопутствующем бонусе» ведётся речь.

Comment: Я бы не торопился принимать ответ, пока проблема ещё не решена. То есть Ник, конечно, сюда заглянет, но всё же. :)

Comment: @Discord, опередил Вас на секунды, снял.

Comment: Поддерживаю. Тут надо принимать меры, прежде чем считать вопрос решённым :) Можно в ответах пока заняться предложением вариантов... наверное.

Answer (score 6):

Всё верно, это он и есть.

Похоже, что **ссылки правильные**. Но по меньшей мере **перепутаны местами**.

> Вопрос защищен от ответов в духе «Спасибо!», «У меня тоже!» или спама, публикуемого новичками. Чтобы опубликовать ответ, вам необходимо заработать не менее 10 баллов [репутации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) на сайте ( [бонус за ассоциацию учётных записей не учитывается](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user)).

Если ссылки переместить, становится получше:

> Вопрос защищен от ответов в духе «Спасибо!», «У меня тоже!» или спама, публикуемого новичками. Чтобы опубликовать ответ, вам необходимо [заработать не менее 10 баллов репутации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) на сайте ([бонус за ассоциацию учётных записей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) не учитывается).

Comment: Если так, то на [**данной странице**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user), полагаю, будет нелишней гиперссылка к выражению *сопутствующий бонус*.

Comment: @СашаЧерных да и само выражение стоит заменить, раз уж на то пошло. Потому что к слову "сопутствующий" не видно "сопутствующий чему".

Comment: А ещё пробел был лишний перед скобкой )

Answer (score 3):

Я бы ещё добавил ссылку на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions. И вместо "новичков" что-нибудь менее эмоционально окрашенное.

> [Вопрос защищен](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) от ответов в духе «Спасибо!», «У меня тоже!» или спама, публикуемого новыми участниками...

Comment: Как насчёт "ньюфагов" или "нубасов"?

Comment: @Discord а также "шпана", "духи" и т.п. Пускай не думают, что мы им тут рады. =)